# How to correctly pass variables & source version to API 2.0 VNext Build in TFS 2015

Tags: json, powershell, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I'm having difficulty finding how the correct way to pass **defined variables**  and **build definition arguments** to the new API 2.0 build engine with TFS 2015. I'm using **TFS 2015 Update 3 on-premise** .

I've triggered a POST with powershell that looks like this:

```
$Build_Definition_ID = 1234
$TFSInstanceURL = 'http://tfsservername:port/tfs'
$ProjectCollection = 'CollectionName'
$TeamProject = 'ProjectName'
$Changeset = "12345"
$UserName = "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME"
$UserNamePartial = $env:USERNAME


$body = @"
   {
       "definition": {
           "id": "$Build_Definition_ID"
       }
   }
"@

$baseUri = $TFSInstanceURL+"/"+$ProjectCollection+"/"+$TeamProject+"/_apis/build"
$postUri = $baseUri+"/builds?api-version=2.0"

##Create a new PSCredential based on username/password
$User =  'foo\bar'
$Password  =  'examplepass' 
$securePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $securePassword)

### Queue a build ###
##Call the REST API for TFS that does a POST request to queue a build with the body of the request to be the build definition
$buildResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Credential $credential -ContentType application/json -Uri $postUri -Body $body

#Write-Host (ConvertTo-Json $buildResponse)
#ConvertTo-Json $buildResponse | out-file  -FilePath $Changeset-ResponseJson.json -Force
```

The powershell script is successfully launching the definition. However, I'm still not successfully:
- Passing in the specific source version I want to run against (example C12345)
- Passing in the custom variable values

Additionally: 
If you know of the proper way to pass in the arguments such as the folder to map from source (to allow dynamically choosing different branches) then this would help.

Current resources I've evaluated:

- [Visual Studio Docs > Api > Build > Builds](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds)
- Postman - GET - Definition Details - Reviewed response for possible correct structure to submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body part for the REST API should look like:

```
{
  "definition": {
    "id": 28
  },
  "sourceBranch": "$/xxxx/xxxx",
  "SourceVersion": "Cxxxx",
}
```

Then you can specify the sourceBranch and SourceVersion.

===================================================================

An example:

```
$Build_Definition_ID = '28'
$TFSInstanceURL = 'http://tfsservername:port/tfs'
$ProjectCollection = 'DefaultCollection'
$TeamProject = 'TestCase'
$Changeset = "C139"
$sourceBranch = "$/TestCase/TestCaseProject-branch"

$body = @"
   {
       "definition": {
           "id": "$Build_Definition_ID"
       },
       "sourceBranch": "$sourceBranch",
       "SourceVersion": "$Changeset",
   }
"@
```

Comment: can you provide insight on the variables. That would complete the full problem I was trying to work through. Thanks!

Comment: ok. I'll give that a shot and update with any issues. thanks for your time in providing a good example. Hopefully this will fit the bill

Comment: @Cece-MSFT what version of TFS does one need to get 'SourceVersion' to work. I can't seem to make it work :(