# TFS 2017 REST: Queue Build with Changeset

Tags: rest, xaml, tfs

Is there a way to queue a (XAML) build on TFS with a specific changeset via the REST API?

I already tried this, which queues the build but uses the latest changeset. Not the one I specified.

```
POST https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version={version}
{
    "definition": {
        "id": 28
    },
    "sourceBranch": "$/xxxx/xxxx",
    "SourceVersion": "Cxxxx",
}
```

I found this solution here: [How to correctly pass variables & source version to API 2.0 VNext Build in TFS 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747741/how-to-correctly-pass-variables-source-version-to-api-2-0-vnext-build-in-tfs-2?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But it is for TFS 2015 and vNext builds. What I'm looking for is 2017 and XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not queue a XAML build with a specific changeset via the REST API.

If you want to queue a Xaml build with the specific changeset, then you can edit the build definition and specify the specific changeset in **Get Version** (Reference below screenshot).

Besides, the REST API you mentioned ([Build (2.0](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/overview))) is for VNext build although it works when specify the build definition ID.

In general, for Xaml build, you can use request a build with below REST API (See [Request a build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/xamlbuild/requests#request-a-build)):

```
POST https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/requests?api-version={version}

Content-Type: application/json

{
    "definition": {
        "id": 4
    },
    "reason": "manual",
    "priority": "Normal",
}
```

[image]